# How many $6$-digit positive integers are there in which the sum of the digits is at most $51$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many $6$-digit positive integers are there in which the sum of the digits is at most $51$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hint:  First find the number of all 6-digit integers.  Then count the ones that do not satisfy the requirements, that is, those with digit sum of at least 52.

Comment: Alternatively, you could also find all ways that six digits could sum up to at least 52 and work on permutations of those.

Comment: alright thx guys

Comment: @Frank: Given that $6\times 9 = 54$, herpderp's answer is likely to be quicker, as well as reducing the complications of leading $0$s

Comment: @Henry Definitely possible.  I just thought I'd give an alternative solution in case it helped someone.

Answer (score 0):

$$6.9 > 51$$

$$5.9+8 > 51$$

$$4.9+8.9 =52 >51$$

$$3.9+3.8 < 51$$

Now just the permutation part. You can use maximum of three $9$'s in your 6-digit number(Only constrain).